# Dialog cut off in RTL language android

Tags: android

I have this code to display a custom dialog in android. It works fine only if current language is not RTL. Once we change language to Arabic, the dialog cuts off:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(activityContext, R.style.MaterialDialogSheet);
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(activityContext);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.error_dialog_view, null);
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    dialog.setCancelable(isCancelable);
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(isCancelable);

    TextView errorTittleTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.error_title);
    TextView errorMessageTextView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.error_message);

    errorTittleTextView.setText(activityContext.getString(R.string.error_dialog_title).toUpperCase());
    errorMessageTextView.setText(errorMessage.toUpperCase());

    return dialog;
```

[image: Arabic dialog]

Although in English it shows like this:
[image: English Dialog]

What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you set support RTL in Android manifest? Also check layout without round corners

Comment: supportsRtl="true" in manifest. Let me check the round corners

Comment: Tried without round corners but issue still persists.

Comment: I used this dialog fragment in many project and works fine it may help you https://github.com/AmirHadifar/Flashcard/blob/master/app/src/main/java/net/hadifar/dope/ui/fragment/dialogs/MessageDialog.java

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution? i'm encountering the same issue..

Comment: any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed when I changed the XML layout of the dialog from:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

to

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```